# Sum of only positive data of the column when aggregation in spark dataset

Tags: apache-spark, aggregate-functions

I have a sample dataset  as below

```
+------+------+--------+
| col1 | col2 | values |
+------+------+--------+
| abc  | def  | -4     |
+------+------+--------+
| abc  | def  | 4      |
+------+------+--------+
| abc  | efg  | 8      |
+------+------+--------+
```

When aggregation of the above dataset I need the sum of `values` (only positive) when grouping by `col1, col2` 
as below

```
+------+------+--------+
| col1 | col2 | values |
+------+------+--------+
| abc  | def  | 4      |
+------+------+--------+
| abc  | efg  | 8      |
+------+------+--------+
```

Now I get it as

```
+------+------+--------+
| col1 | col2 | values |
+------+------+--------+
| abc  | def  | 0      |
+------+------+--------+
| abc  | efg  | 8      |
+------+------+--------+
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would not filter before aggregation, because you may need the other rows for a different aggregation. Just formulate your requirement directly in the `agg` clause as :

```
df
  .groupBy($"col1",$"col2")
  .agg(
    sum(when($"values">0,$"values")).as("values") // sum of positive values
  )
```

Answer (score 1):

You can replace negative values with zero, then do the aggregation. The following is a demo with pyspark. It should be similar with other languages:

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as f

df.groupBy('col1', 'col2').agg(
    f.sum(
        f.when(f.col('values') < 0, 0).otherwise(f.col('values'))
    ).alias('values')
).show()

+----+----+------+
|col1|col2|values|
+----+----+------+
| abc| def|     4|
| abc| efg|     8|
+----+----+------+
```

Answer (score 0):

You can filter the Dataset before the aggreagation

```
  df
    .filter(col("values") > 0)
    .groupBy("col1", "col2")
    .agg(sum("values").as("values"))
    .show()

+----+----+------+
|col1|col2|values|
+----+----+------+
| abc| def|     4|
| abc| efg|     8|
+----+----+------+
```

Answer (score -1):

```
val sparkSession = SparkSession.builder.config("spark.master","local").getOrCreate()
    import sparkSession.implicits._
val someDF = Seq(("abc","def",-4),("abc","def",4),("abc","efg",8)).toDF("col1","col2","values")
    someDF.filter("values>0").groupBy("col1","col2").sum("values").show()


+----+----+-----------+
|col1|col2|sum(values)|
+----+----+-----------+
| abc| def|          4|
| abc| efg|          8|
+----+----+-----------+
```